# How to unit test that os.walk triggers an error handler?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

```
# my_module.py

def walk_error_handler(os_error_instance):
    logger.error(...)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, onerror=walk_error_handler):
    ...
```

How to unit test that `os.walk`, should it encounter an `OSError`, calls the custom handler?

I tried to do this by creating a temporary file in a temporary directory, and then restricting the permissions of the directory.  Unfortunately that crashed the test runner.  Looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you looked at how the stdlib tests `os.walk` for inspiration?  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_os.py#L986

Comment: *"Unfortunately that crashed the test runner."* I'd be most concerned about *that*.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you can't simply mock `walk_error_handler` in the unit test and check that it does something.. like write to a file, or the likes.

Comment: @nir0s  I can and will.  But you need to trigger `os.walk` to raise the OSError somehow.

Comment: Did you try creating a file and changing its permissions on the fly? before os.walk-ing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're not testing `os.walk` but that a function which uses `os.walk` has correctly set up their error handler and that it handles an `OSError` correctly. There's two questions the test is asking.

1. Does the function call the correct error handler?
2. Does that error handler handle an `OSError` correctly?

Rather than trying to get `os.walk` to generate an `OSError`, you only need it to generate *any* error. And rather than testing the error handler through `os.walk` you can get it directly.

For the first, call `os.walk` with some path you know doesn't exist. Check if the error handler got run. All you're testing is the correct error handler runs.

For the second, call the error handler directly with an `OSError` object. All you're testing is that the error handler handles an `OSError` object.

Comment: Good idea   it hadn't occurred to me that the handler would be called for non-existing root.